# Issue with qgis 3graphcis

Tags: qgis-3

I am using the latest installation of QGIS (3.2) in a Macos Sierra 10.12.6 and I get those graphic issues on the top left of the software (see image). Also when I go to full screen the tool tabs get duplicated (second image). Does anyone else has the same issue? Is it related with my graphics card? I have tried to toggle off/on the toolbars but this doesn't fix the issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: 3.2.0 works fine on High Sierra. I think the shrunken screen was a common problem with one particular version of QGIS (3.2.1 maybe?) on the Mac. Not seen the tab duplication before, though. Is this the latest build (3.2.2-1 as of today)?

Comment: @StevenKay I use Sierra but I am upgrading right now in the latest version and I will check if it works. I was thinking it could be an issue with QT version? Would that make sense?

Comment: it was a general issue with QGIS. There were a lot of questions about this about a month or two ago (although I don't seem to be able to find them, typical ;-) If that's when you downloaded it, try downloading the latest QGIS

Comment: @StevenKay still the same issue. I upgraded my OS to the latest version and downloaded the last version for QGIS. But it doesnt seem to work.